# Python screenshot to base64

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Here is the way I take screenshots:

```
import wx

app = wx.App(False)
s = wx.ScreenDC()
w, h = s.Size.Get()
b = wx.EmptyBitmap(w, h)
m = wx.MemoryDCFromDC(s)
m.SelectObject(b)
m.Blit(0, 0, w, h, s, 0, 0)
m.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)
b.SaveFile("hey.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
```

I don't want to save the screenshot as an image file "hey.png", I want it as base64 string. 
My final purpose is just to print the base64 string, then I want to **put it manually in html code**, here:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,here" />
```

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to somehow get the bytes of that file. This can be done two ways:

1. Through the wx API, if possible (I am familair with the API but you should be able to look it up if it is possible)
2. By saving the file, reading the file and finally deleting the file.

For the actual encoding, you can use the built in [base64](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) API. Note that I linked to the Python 2 wiki instead of the Python 3 wiki, since to my knowledge wxPython is only available for python 2.

Comment: I've thought about the second option but I found it a bit inefficient, I even checked it, and it works fine, but I would like to use the first option if it's possible and to avoid the image file creation. My python version is 2.7. Can you tell me how can I do the first option? It's a long time that I'm trying to do it, that's actually why I came to ask here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @guyshitz I looked around for you but it does not seem possible at a first glance to retrieve the PNG binary data without that file, as the conversion to PNG is done in that method.

Comment: @engineercoding, just so you know - wxPython for python 3.x is available and it is called Phoenix. There is no official release of the Phoenix yet, but Robin is working on it currently and hopefully we will see a release soon. You can, as an alternative, build Phoenix yourself from sources - it is available and works.

Comment: In C++ you can save an image to a stream, including `wxMemoryOutputStream`. I don't know if this `SaveFile()` overload is available from Python however.